# Strange (almost) anonymous instance

Tags: scala, scala-3

In the Scala Reference page on [Using Clauses](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/using-clauses.html) there is code like this:

```
trait Ord[T]:    // From the previous page
  def compare(x: T, y: T): Int
  extension (x: T) def < (y: T) = compare(x, y) < 0
  extension (x: T) def > (y: T) = compare(x, y) > 0

def descending[T](using asc: Ord[T]): Ord[T] = new Ord[T]:
    def compare(x: T, y: T) = asc.compare(y, x)
```

I've not seen anything like the `new Ord[T]: ...` before.  It is almost like an anonymous class but using a `:` instead of braces.  Is it the same thing?  I've just not seen this construct before.

Comment: Given you don't need braces to define the trait why do you find so amusing that you don't need them for the instance?

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing. But this is Scala 3. You probably have been coding in Scala 2 so far, that's why you have not seen it before. With Scala 3, you can optionally use the off-side rule (indenting) to structure blocks of code, if you want. Much like Python's indentation style.

Comment: Thanks, Luis and Alin.  I've been away from Scala for a long time and had forgotten about anonymous instances and had to do some googling to even find a reference to them.  Then I found them in Programming in Scala (3rd edition).  But everywhere I saw them they used braces.  So I'm glad to see it is something reasonably simple.